# Add headers to multipart/form-data POST request to node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I cannot seem to set any headers on the following POST request for upload of a photo to a node.js. The headers are present but missing the x-access-token. I'm logging the request headers to the console as the request comes in and there is no 'x-access-token' and my user fails authentication at this step with my node.js middleware that authorizes the token is present for protected routes.

I've tried the below with a req.param by appending the token to the url but this does not work and throws an CANNOT POST /photo error in the browser.

```
var auth = localStorage.getItem('token');
$.ajax({
    url: '/photo',
    headers: {'x-access-token': auth},
    data: new FormData( this ),
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: "POST",
    success:function(result, success) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    },
    error:function(result, success) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }
});
```

logged request headers:

```
14:49:54 web.1  | request headers { host: 'localhost:5000',
14:49:54 web.1  |   connection: 'keep-alive',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'content-length': '38477',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
14:49:54 web.1  |   accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
14:49:54 web.1  |   origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryA9UW3T02fcX803jG',
14:49:54 web.1  |   dnt: '1',
14:49:54 web.1  |   referer: 'http://localhost:5000/profile/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjozLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Imhhc2hlZG1hbiIsImlhdCI6MTQzODg4Njk4NywiZXhwIjoxNDM4OTczMzg3fQ.upLUzkW2g2nQEdga6_hvvyzgTD0H2ciwYLA6zR0T_C4',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
14:49:54 web.1  |   'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6' }
```

Comment: That too vague. How do you know things aren't working as they should? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: edited please have a look

Comment: Are you sure `auth` is actually defined?

Comment: Yeah, it definitely is